# android How to get Exact travelled distance by android device

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I don't want to use Google direction API services. want to exact location traveled by phone. And right now I am using gps like :
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

this is giving me distance. But if i stay one place not running, driving distance also calculated in total distance and finally getting wrong distance.
any better idea to calulate right distance between the points ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want to achieve. My best guess is that you want to save different locations when you are moving and calculate the distance between this points. I would suggest you save the location points in the internal database and then calculate [like this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) your distance. You have to save the longitude and latitude by `longitude.getLongitude` and vice versa. 
Hopefully this will help.

Comment: I used distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB); method and used gps to calculate distance between last point and current point and measuring distance in 0 milisecond and 0 meter and calculate after trip end. I am creating an application for loading riksha that gives the exact distance whatever distance travelled by loading riksha. But gps not give exact distance it calculated distance also if riksha is stopped not in running condition.